# Epson sx515w wifi dropout

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have n Epson sx515w all in one printer which until recently, has worked as it should over my network. Now the printer drops wifi connection when it goes into sleep mode. (it turns the wifi off, as the wifi light goes out) Re-establishing a connection cannot be achieved as pressing any of the network button to set this up again result in the printer screen returning back to the beginning of the set-up without going onto the next stage...! If I turn off the printer and then back on again, the connection is once again re-established and the printer works as it should..!

The household has 3 laptops, 2 desktop PC's (all running win 7 64bit) and various android phones and tablets on the network. None of them have any network issues and can all access the printer , until the printer drops from the network.

I have un-installed the printer on the master pc. Reset, the printer, re-installed the pc with the latest software and brought it back on line, but the problem still remains when it goes into sleep mode, and I have to keep re starting the printer each time.
This is getting very annoying now, and I need to get this sorted, hence this message in hoping someone in the know can help me solve this annoying problem..!!!

Comment: Firmare update?

Answer (score 1):

With problems like yours, I would try to reset the printer to factory defaults. For your printer, the only suggestion I could find on how to do it is this:

1.Switch printer off. Remove all the cables from the printer. I would try switching the router off as well, to ensure there's no WiFi.
2.Wait for 10 mins.
3.Connect only the power cord and power on the printer. Then switch on the router.

I found it here: http://www.justanswer.com/printers/6c40q-paper-jam-epson-sx515w-successfully-cleared.html#ixzz3PDLpxgZv

Comment: I would try to use this printer only with ethernet cable after doing a reset factory settings.
Wifi settings is not its strongest feature and I am a professional software developer so I know perfectly what I am doing with the wifi settings.
So just use the ethernet cable to connect it to the router.